# Groovy: indexes of substrings?

Tags: groovy

How do I find the indexes of all the occurances of a substring in a large string - 
(so basically ,and extension of the "indexOf" function) . Any ideas?

**Current situation:**

```
def text  = " --- --- bcd -- bcd ---" 
def sub = "bcd"
text.indexOf(sub) 
// = 9
```

**I want something like:**

```
def text  = " --- --- bcd -- bcd ---" 
def sub = "bcd"
text.indexesOf(sub) 
// = [9,15]
```

Is there such a function? How should I implement it otherwise? (in a non trivial way)

Comment: What is your question? "How do I implement it?" or "Is there such a thing?" or "...?"

Comment: I rephrased the question , thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a new addition to the `String` metaClass like so:

```
String.metaClass.indexesOf = { match ->
  def ret = []
  def idx = -1
  while( ( idx = delegate.indexOf( match, idx + 1 ) ) > -1 ) {
    ret << idx
  }
  ret
}

def text  = " --- --- bcd -- bcd ---" 
def sub = "bcd"
text.indexesOf(sub)
```

There is nothing I know of that exists in groovy currently that gets you this for free though

Comment: hehehe..  what `println`? ;-)  _*whistles innocently*_

Comment: I guess you had the same infinite loop that I had earlier ;-) darn those off-by-one errors

Comment: Hahaha, yeah...  I thought the `int` in `indexOf` was exclusive ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This is a relatively easy approach:

```
String.metaClass.indexesOf = { arg ->
  def result = []
  int index = delegate.indexOf(arg)
  while (index != -1) {
    result.add(index);
    index = delegate.indexOf(arg, index+1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Note that this *will* find overlapping instances (i.e. `"fooo".indexesOf("oo")` will return `[1, 2]`). If you don't want this, replace `index+1` with `index+arg.length()`.